# How to multiply textbox value using javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVFeedType" runat="server" Style="margin-bottom: 6px" BorderColor="#BDBDBD"
    CssClass="center" Width="500px" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        No Records found</EmptyDataTemplate>
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="SNo" DataField="SNo" ItemStyle-Width="50px" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Feed Type" DataField="FeedType" ItemStyle-Width="200px" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate/Kg" ItemStyle-Width="80px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtrate" runat="server" Width="100px" OnTextChanged="txtrate_TextChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true" />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RFVrecdate1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtrate"
                    Display="None" ErrorMessage="Must Enter Rate" ValidationGroup="duereport"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate/50 Kg" ItemStyle-Width="80px">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl50kg" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I tried this code..

```
protected void txtrate_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    GridViewRow currentRow = (GridViewRow)(sender as TextBox).Parent.Parent;
    float rate = 0;
    float kgrate50 = 50;

    rate = Convert.ToSingle((sender as TextBox).Text.Trim());
    kgrate50 = rate * kgrate50;
    (currentRow.Cells[3].FindControl("lbl50kg") as Label).Text = kgrate50.ToString();
    GVFeedType.Rows[currentRow.RowIndex + 1].Cells[2].FindControl("txtrate").Focus();
}
```

This code is fine ,Tab not working...
i have a textbox in a grid view control,when i enter some value like 2,3,4 ..then it multiply with 50 ...and it shows output in lable control..here label also in a gridview..how can i solve it..please help me..

Answer (score 0):

I would add CSs class to text box

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtrate" runat="server" CssClass="TextBoxToHandle" Width="100px" OnTextChanged="txtrate_TextChanged"
                    AutoPostBack="true" />
```

Since using tab throw focusout event you need to subscribe to it

```
$(function(){
  $(".TextBoxToHandle").focusout(function(){
    //Do your code here this would be element which you focus left
  });
})
```